# Sync FAT32 usb thumb drive with folder on HFS+ Mac OS X

Tags: macos, sync, hfs, usb-storage

I have a couple usb thumb drives that I use on both a Windows desktop and my Macbook.  I want to be able to sync the files from the usb drive(s) with corresponding folders on my Macbook (i.e. one folder for usb stick #1, another folder for stick #2, etc.).

I started out trying to use Carbon Copy Cloner... but apparently it only works with drives that are formatted in HFS+ (OS X native), and it won't touch the FAT32 formatted thumb drives.  I can't/won't change the formatting on them as that would render them unusable with Windows.

Any suggestions as to what to try now?

TIA,

Monte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Synkron](http://synkron.sourceforge.net/) would be best-suited for this. I use it daily to sync between my Mac and a Windows share. CCC wouldn't work because it prefers to preserve all OS X metadata only available on an HFS+ filesystem, not FAT32. Synkron only worries about the main data in the files, and does not preserve anything. Thus, it is not good for backing up an entire OS X installation, but good for syncing files. From Synkron's website:

> Synkron is an application for folder synchronisation that allows you to *configure your synchronisations in detail*. Despite having many features, the user interface of Synkron is very user-friendly and *easy to use*.

[image: Synkron screenshot]

Comment: I downloaded Synkron and it seems to fit the bill... plus the price is right and it has the added plus of running on a PC, even in PortableApp form.  Not part of the original question, but definitely something useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

**1)  [ArRsync](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/20983/arrsync)**

[image]

**2)  [ChronoSync](http://www.econtechnologies.com/pages/cs/chrono_overview.html)**